# Multiple ehcache.xml in classpath

Tags: java, ehcache

What will happen if there are multiple ehcache.xml files in the classpath? Which one will be picked up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will depend on CLASSLOADING. Whichever is found first in CLASSPATH will be loaded and will be in effect for rest of your code.

It is same as keeping same JAR file in multiple paths of your CLASSPATH.